# Show only one overlay on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-on

I'm having trouble with my jQuery code, instead of having the overlay appear on hover, all of them appear when I hover over one.
I have made a JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/fukuw/8/
If you hover over the images, all the overlays appear but what's intended is for the one that you are hovering over to appear.
Also how can I make that code work for touch users?

Comment: I am still learning jquery but I think you need to use `$(this)` to only affect the one you are interacting with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you are not telling the correct element to animate - you have to use `this`  and find the overlay that belongs to the element you're hovering over ...

```
 SaveElement.on("mouseover", function () {
    $(this).find(".overlay").animate({ opacity: 1, top: "3px" }, 150);
  });

  SaveElement.on("mouseleave", function () {
     $(this).find(".overlay").animate({ opacity: 0, top: "-23px" }, 150);
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/wuribezonoji/1

Comment: Thanks very much. This will surely help!